# C# Group by Multiple Fields and select them as List

Tags: c#

I have few list **`List<Parent>`** where `Parent` class is

```
public class Parent
{
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public List<PhysicalRule> PhysicalRules { get; set; }
}

public class PhysicalRule
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string LayerGroup { get; set; }
    public string NetClassGroup { get; set; }
    public List<RuleProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }

}
public class RuleProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to group the `List<Parent>` as

```
{
    NetClassGroup1
    [
        {
            Region: region1
            List<PhysicalRules>
        },
        {
            Region: region2
            List<PhysicalRules>
        },
        {
            Region: region3
            List<PhysicalRules>
        }
    ]

    NetClassGroup2
    [
        {
            Region: region1
            List<PhysicalRules>
        },
        {
            Region: region2
            List<PhysicalRules>
        },
        {
            Region: region3
            List<PhysicalRules>
        }
    ]
}
```

The order of Region objects should be the same in all the NetclassGroup Objects. I am planning to sort by Region name...but not sure how to construct this structure form the data objects that I have.

Comment: Your question is really too broad. But, you can use LINQ's "group by" to group each list by `NetClassGroup`. See duplicates. You can use `SelectMany()` to flatten the original collection of lists into individual `PhysicalRule` objects before grouping, then after the grouping by `NetClassGroup`, perform another grouping within each of those groups to recover `Parent` objects for each of those groups.

Comment: `
 var query = from parent in parentsList 
    orderby parent.RegionName
    from phisicalRule in parent.PhysicalRules
    group parent by phisicalRule.NetClassGroup into grp
       select grp;
   
 var dic = query.ToDictionary(q=>q.Key);
`